# How to persist with hibernate-reactive and complex id?

Tags: java, hibernate, reactive-programming, reactive, hibernate-reactive

i have an error when i want to persist with Hibernate-reactive (hibernate-reactive-core 2.0.6.Final) & spring-boot & java17.

My entity :

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Entity
@IdClass(MyTableId.class)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyTableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_1")
    private String code1;

    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private Long num;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_2")
    private String code2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

The class ID :

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyTableId implements Serializable {
    private String code1;
    private String code2;
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

My repository :

```java
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyTableRepository {

    private Stage.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Mono<Void> save(MyTableEntity myTableEntity) {
        return Mono.fromCompletionStage(
                sessionFactory.withSession(
                    session -> session.persist(myTableEntity)
                ));
    }

// ... others methods to find in MyTable
```

But i have an error when i call session.persist :

> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@68e22cdc[Completed exceptionally: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String myPackage.MyTableEntity.code2] by reflection for persistent property [myPackageEntity#code2] : MyTableEntity(code1=CODE_1, num=3, code2=ABCD1234, date=2023-11-08T21:21:39.835527200
> ... ... ... ... ...
> caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field myPackage.MyTableEntity.code2 to myPackage.MyTableEntity
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)

For information, I have two others methods who find the entity and they work ... For example :

```java
public Mono<MyTableEntity> findBlablabla(String code1) {
        return Mono.fromCompletionStage(
                sessionFactory.withSession(
                        session ->
                                session
                                        .createQuery("""
                                                        SELECT m from MyTableEntity m
                                                        WHERE c.code1 like :code1
                                                        ORDER BY c.date DESC
                                                        LIMIT 1
                                                        """
                                                , MyTableEntity.class)
                                        .setParameter("code1", code1)
                                        .getSingleResultOrNull()
                )
        );
    }
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating getters and setters for those private fields?

From the [documentation](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/reference/html_single/):

> 1.3.2. Getters and setters When using Hibernate Reactive outside the Quarkus environment, you’ll need to write your entity classes
> according to the usual JPA conventions, which require:
>
> private fields for persistent attributes, and
>
> a nullary constructor.

Comment: Yes, i tried @Data from Lombok and i tried with getters/setters generated.
Nothing changes :(